# How to prove the Cartesian Product of a set is numerically equivalent to real numbers

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, definition, proof-explanation, infinite-groups

Set $A = \{0, 1\}$.

Prove that the set $S=\prod\limits_{i \in Z^+}A$ is numerically equivalent to $R$.

If I understand correctly I need to establish a bijective function between set $S$ and real numbers $R$.

I am very confused about what a Cartesian Product from $i \in Z^+$ implies.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\prod_{i\in \Bbb Z^+}A$ is usually imagined as the set of infinitely long binary strings. Also, it is a whole lot easier to construct one injection either way than to construct a virgin between the two, so I suggest you try that instead.

Comment: Than to construct a bijection*... Damn autocorrect.

Comment: @Arthur - Not that the construction of a virgin from these data wouldn't be mathematically significant.

Comment: @Arthur. That auto-correct error made me laugh.

Comment: Are you familiar with the existence of a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and th set of all subsets of $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Arthur Thank you for the advice. Will an injection prove that they are numerically equivalent? I was under the impression that the function I find will also have to be surjective?

Comment: @user254665 I'm afraid I'm not familiar with that bijection, or what $\mathbb N$ signifies.

Comment: $\mathbb N$ on this site usually means the positive integers. Not what I prefer, but I accede to it.